# image.plot does not create new image

Tags: r, plot

Here is a sample of code that produces a image plot. But for some reason, when I re-run it, no new image is created but it overlays the existing plot. However I expect it to create a new image, certainly as it has a specific parameter 'add' to specify that it has to be added to the existing plot (but default value is FALSE).

Does anybody know what is going on here?

```
require(fields)

mat <- matrix(runif(5*5), ncol=5) 

mat[1,3] <- NA

image.plot(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1), mat, col = tim.colors(64), legend.only=TRUE)
par(oma=c(0,0,0,6))
par(new = TRUE)
image(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1),matrix(1,5,5), col = gray(0.8), xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F)
par(new = TRUE)
image(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1),mat, xlab="Hour of the Day", ylab = "Day of the Week", col = tim.colors(64), axes = F)
par(oma=c(0,0,0,0))
```

**EDIT**
I don't know much about devices etc. But I do know that (and I am working in RStudio) when I do eg first `plot(1:10)` and then `plot(10:1)` that the figure window is cleared and the second plot is shown without being added to the first one (in RStudio you have off course the additional functionality that you can also browse your previous figures, but if I do the same in a plain R console, the plotting window is cleared when the second plot is called). And *that* is what I want, I just expect that the figure window is cleared when I call image.plot a second time, instead of overlaying the image from the previous time I called image.plot.

Comment: If you will describe what at what point you want to switch over to a new ... er, different ... image we can probably help. At the moment I cannot tell. Or were you expecting  a new plot window? If so, then follow @joran's advice and read the help page: `?dev.new`

Comment: @DWin I added some further explanation. I hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 3):

You are noticing the odd reversal in meaning for the "new" parameter to `par`. Here's the help page description:

`new`

```
logical, defaulting to FALSE. If set to TRUE, the next high-level plotting command 
(actually plot.new) should not clean the frame before drawing as if it were on a new 
device. It is an error (ignored with a warning) to try to use new = TRUE on a device 
that does not currently contain a high-level plot.
```

Comment: The end result being that the OP will likely want to explicitly call `quartz()`, `x11()` or whatever, depending on their platform.

Comment: If your interpretation of the problem is correct then `?dev.new` is probably what @joris needs to read to get cross-platform functionality.

Comment: I think I understand the meaning of the par(new) correctly. For producing the plot, I call three times `image`. And because the second and third time it has to be added to the first call I use `par(new=TRUE`). But after the third `image` call, when I want to make another similar graph, I expect R to clean the frame when I use `image.plot` again.

Comment: Then use `new.dev()`. If you want the old interactive graphics device to disappear, then close then first by using `dev.off()`

Comment: `dev.new()` does not seem to work in RStudio (I get the warning message "Only one RStudio graphics device is permitted"). `dev.off()` indeed works to clear the frame to make a new plot, but then I lose the previous figure in RStudio (cannot look at it again by browsing the previous figures).

Comment: Ooops. I misspelled the function name for dev.new(). The Rstudio environment appears to some sort of plot-viewer that appears to provide back-scrolling through a queue positioning icon-arrow in the "RStudio Plots Pane". Are you a new user of RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set `legend.only=T` in the `image.plot` command, it automatically sets `par(new=TRUE)`. If you plot the images first and after that add the legend, it works. Here you have to leave away one `par(new=TRUE)`:

```
require(fields)

mat <- matrix(runif(5*5), ncol=5) 

mat[1,3] <- NA

par(oma=c(0,0,0,6))
#par(new = TRUE)
image(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1),matrix(1,5,5), col = gray(0.8), xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F)
par(new = TRUE)
image(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1),mat, xlab="Hour of the Day", ylab = "Day of the Week", col = tim.colors(64), axes = F)
par(oma=c(0,0,0,0))
image.plot(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1), mat, col = tim.colors(64), legend.only=TRUE)
```