# Two logarithmic y axis histograms in one R studio diagram

Tags: r, histogram, rstudio, logarithm

I am using RStudio to draw the histogram of the values in this [data](https://github.com/alisajedi/repo3/blob/master/test.csv).

```
data = read.table("C:\\Test\\test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
hist(data$a, breaks=100)
hist(data$b, breaks=100)
```

and got the following histograms:

[image]
[image]
But I want to:

1- have the y axis logged so that instead of values 0, 4000, 8000 and 12000 I'll have 0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 and so on (log2 i.e., 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... is also useful).

2- Have the two diagrams in a single diagram (preferably with bars of two different colors/patterns). In the resulting diagram, the two bars for each x-value would be beside each other like this:
[image]

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828248/make-y-axis-logarithmic-in-histogram-using-r) but got the following error:

> NULL
>
> Warning message: In (function ()  : Only one RStudio graphics
>
> device is permitted

Comment: You've some histograms bars with height very close to zero in your graph. You might want to do something about that before applying log scale.

Comment: And why this question is tagged rstudio?

Comment: @Narendra, having the small values is the reason why I want log scaling. Instead of showing 0 as the small values, I want to show both small values and big values in the same diagram.

Comment: @Narendra, I have seen in a comment ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798967/image-plot-does-not-create-new-image ) that dev.new() which is part of the offered solution that I linked is not working in RStudio. So I added RStudio as a related tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I devised inspired from Teja_K 's answer:

```
data = read.table("C:\\test\\test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
par( mar=c(3.1, 5.1, 0, 0)) 
hist.x <- hist(data$a, plot = FALSE, breaks=50)
hist.x$counts <- log10(hist.x$counts + 1)
plot(hist.x, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.99), main="", xlab="", ylab="", yaxt="n")
yAxesTitles=c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000)
axis(2, at=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),labels=yAxesTitles, col.axis="black", las=2)
mtext(side = 1, text = "Number", line = 2)
mtext(side = 2, text = "Frequency", line = 4)
# Adding the second diagram to the first one:
relocatedData=data$b+0.2
hist.y <- hist(relocatedData, plot = FALSE, breaks=50)
hist.y$counts <- log10(hist.y$counts + 1)
plot(hist.y, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.99), main="", xlab="", ylab="", yaxt="n", add=TRUE)
legend(7.5, 4, c("a", "b"), lwd=c(1, 1), col=c(rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.99), rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.99)), pch = c(15, 15), pt.cex=2)
```

---

And the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
## Create fake data
x <- c(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 20000), rep(3, 800), rep(4, 10000))
y <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 1000), rep(3, 10000), rep(4, 2000))

## Plot x
hist.x <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
hist.x$counts <- log10(hist.x$counts + 1)
plot(hist.x, col = rgb(0, 0, 1, 0.25))

## Plot y
hist.y <- hist(y, plot = FALSE)
hist.y$counts <- log10(hist.y$counts + 1)
plot(hist.y, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.25), add = TRUE)
```

which results in this:

[image]

If you would like them to be next to each other, just add

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
```

at the top and change the plot command for y to `

plot(hist.y, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, 0.25))

The resulting plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: @alisa, I added an edit to show how you can do it in two diagrams beside each other!

Comment: everything is fine, but I want the bars in one single diagram, beside each other. I have edited the question and put a sample output example.